# How can I make custom locations in nginx?

Tags: http, nginx, lua

I have an app running behind nginx. To allow customers to add their own tools under the same hostname we use a `location` sort of like this:

```
location /some-extension {
  rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://customers-app/$1/$args;
}
```

Now, I would like to make this dynamic so that a given customer can create zero or more such locations. Since the app gets deployed with Docker this can't be done my manually editing the nginx configuration.

Nginx is compiled with perl and lua support, so I was thinking about something like this:

- use an evironment variable on the form `path1 url1 path-2 url2 ... pathn urln` to configure an external tool.
- In a special `location` configuration, match the first path segment of the request URL with the environment variable and `proxy_pass` to the corresponding URL if found.

So far, this is what I have:

```
location / {
    content_by_lua '
      local target_path = ngx.var.uri;
      local name = nil

      if target_path:len() > 0 then
        startAt = target_path:find("/") + 1
        endAt = target_path:find("/", startAt) - 1
        name = target_path:sub(startAt,endAt)
        ngx.say(name)
      end

      if name then
        local custom_proxies = os.getenv("CUSTOM_PROXIES");
        inString = custom_proxies:find("another ")
        if not inString then
          ngx.say("not in string")
        else
          startAt = custom_proxies:find(" ", inString + 1) + 1
          endAt = custom_proxies:find(" ", startAt)

          url = custom_proxies:sub(startAt,endAt)
          ngx.say(url)

        end
      end

    ';
  }
```

I know I shouldn't be using `content_by_lua` but it seems to sort of work. The question is how can I get this to `proxy_pass` to the specified URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it the following way:

- The environment variable should be a space separated list of names and URLs; `key http://example.com/app1 key2 http://acme.com`.
- A Lua script reads the environment variable into a `table` where with `key` as key and the following URL as value.
- An nginx `location` block will handle the request and use the Lua script to find the module to proxy to.
- A function will accept the request path and find the key from it then look up the URL in the table.

Here's the script:

```
local custom_proxies = os.getenv("CUSTOM_PROXIES")
local custom_modules = {}

local cutFrom = 0
local cutTo = 0

while cutTo < custom_proxies:len() do
  cutFrom = cutTo
  cutTo = custom_proxies:find(" ", cutFrom + 1)
  local name = custom_proxies:sub(cutFrom, cutTo - 1)
  cutFrom = cutTo + 1
  cutTo = custom_proxies:find(" ", cutFrom)

  if not cutTo then
    cutTo = custom_proxies:len() + 1
  end

  local url = custom_proxies:sub(cutFrom, cutTo - 1)
  custom_modules[name] = url
  cutTo = cutTo + 1
end

function custom_modules.get_url(target_path)
  local name = nil

  local startAt = target_path:find("/", 6) + 1
  local endAt = target_path:find("/", startAt)
  if not endAt then
    endAt = target_path:len()
  else
    endAt = endAt - 1
  end
  name = target_path:sub(startAt,endAt)
  if name then
    return custom_modules[name]
  else
    ngx.log(ngx.STDERR, "Not able to deduct module name from URI")
    return ""
  end
end

return custom_modules
```

Here's the nginx `location`:

```
location /custom/ {
  set_by_lua $redirect_to '
    local custom_modules = require "read_proxies"
    local url = custom_modules.get_url(ngx.var.uri)

    if not url then
      ngx.log(ngx.STDERR, "Not a known custom module.")
    end
    return url
  ';

  if ($redirect_to = '') {
    return 404 'Unknown custom module.';
  }

  rewrite ^/custom/\w+/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass $redirect_to$1?$args;

}
```

The idea is that a request such as `/custom/foobar/path/to/something?page=2` will use `foobar` as a key to look up the URL and `proxy_pass` to it with the rest of the path and args.